# Warning when setting animation parameter from code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a Youtube video for learning Unity,
and I am getting a weird error I do not understand.

```cs
public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpmovement = 11f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float movement = 10f;
    private float movementx;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D mybody;
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private string Walk_Ani = "Player is walking ";
    private SpriteRenderer sr;


    private void Awake1()
    {
        mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Awake1();
        Playerkeymove();
        animateplayer1();
    }
    void Playerkeymove()
    {
        movementx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        // Debug.Log(movementx);
        transform.position += new Vector3(movementx, 0f, 0f) * movement * Time.deltaTime;
       // Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }
    void animateplayer1()
    {
        // anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani , true);
        // we are going to the right side
        if (movementx > 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, true);
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (movementx < 0)
        {
            // we are going to the left side
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, true);
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(Walk_Ani, false);
        }
    }

}
```

The error in my console is on [line 66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGVKq.png). I followed the video exactly and even tried using the video's source code.

Comment: And which is line 66?

Comment: Unity has an Awake function that is automatically called once. What you have with Awake1 and calling it every frame is very wasteful. GetComponent is not cheap.

Comment: @CaiusJard The line number 66 should be the end of the file. The warning being thrown is an internal warning from Unity itself, so the line number is not too helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for the information about awake but how my animation works is 
when the subject is moved it will animate (like walking) and if its idle it will be standard 
 but happened now is  the subject is moving but the animation is not happening

I will be happy if you can take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB1F9G0JXOo&t=13274s this video a the time stamp of 3:54:20

Comment: @SaranRajS The tutorial you linked does not name a function `Awake1`, it also goes over your actual question not even a minute after the timestamp you linked. It specifies that the parameter is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error, it is a [`warning`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html). Unity is telling you that the animation parameter called `Player is walking` , does not exist for your animation that is assigned to your `Animator` on the object that your script exists on.

Along with this code, you will need to have created an [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html) that has the specific [`Animation Paramater`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) called `Player is walking` . If you already have this and followed along with this tutorial you mentioned, it is most likely a typo, and you need to remove the extra trailing space as you currently have `Player is walking` , it might need to be `Player is walking`.

**Edit:** Also, as mentioned in the comments of this question, you most likely want to change the function `Awake1` to `Awake` and **not** call it from `Update`.

```
private void Awake()
{
    mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    Playerkeymove();
    animateplayer1();
}
```

[`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) is a special method used by all Monobehaviour's, which is generally used to initialize references. Calling it every frame is very wasteful as you are continually re-assigning the references of these objects when they do not change.